# RavenDB get total count for query not working

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have this logic in an extension method that creates a paging wrapper:

```
        int total = 0;
        if (query is IRavenQueryable<T>)
        {
            RavenQueryStatistics stats;
            var rQuery = (IRavenQueryable<T>)query;
            rQuery.Statistics(out stats);
            total = stats.TotalResults;
        }
        else
        {
            total = query.Count();
        }
```

My problem is that when I do a raven query, my *stats.TotalResults* is zero, **unless** I hover over *rQuery* during debug and try to expand the results.

What am I doing wrong here?  How to I get raven to consistently give me the results I need?

Here is the whole method:

```
    public static PagingModel<T> Page<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, int page, int count)
    {
        if (page < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Page is one-based and must be greater than zero");

        int total = 0;
        if (query is IRavenQueryable<T>)
        {
            RavenQueryStatistics stats;
            var rQuery = (IRavenQueryable<T>)query;
            rQuery.Statistics(out stats);
            total = stats.TotalResults;
        }
        else
        {
            total = query.Count();
        }

        var results = query
            .Skip((page - 1) * count)
            .Take(count)
            .ToArray();

        return new PagingModel<T>()
        {
            Page = page,
            Rows = results,
            Total = total /count
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  It turns out that *RavenQueryStatistics* sets the *TotalResults* by reference and the total is only available after the results have been resolved.  (I originally thought it made a separate trip to the DB.)

```
    public static PagingModel<T> Page<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, int page, int count)
    {
        RavenQueryStatistics stats = null;
        if (page < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Page is one-based and must be greater than zero");

        if (query is IRavenQueryable<T>)
        {
            var rQuery = (IRavenQueryable<T>)query;
            rQuery.Statistics(out stats);
        }

        var results = query
            .Skip((page - 1) * count)
            .Take(count)
            .ToArray();
        var total = stats == null ? query.Count() : stats.TotalResults;
        return new PagingModel<T>()
        {
            Page = page,
            Rows = results,
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)total / (double)count)
        };
    }
```